# Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?

Tags: discussion, faq, closed-questions, canonical-questions

Where can we store a list of questions that are considered canonical?

Canonical means that it's asked frequently enough to warrant an excellent clear and detailed answer that the site edits and maintains so that it's broad, clear and helps many people troubleshoot or solve a common issue or misunderstanding.

Rather than blame people for coming and asking the same question over and over, the intent is to organize and realize that this will never and and instead have an efficient manner to link these to canonical answers.

That way, if the new asker actually has a different question, it will be easier for them to edit the post and get it reopened. It also will signal to the community that the answers are going to be heavily used and that it's worth it to keep them current, clear, and exemplary so that they can shoulder the burden of answering many questions on the same core topic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## The list of existing canonical questions is here:

#### iCloud and Apple ID accounts in general

##### *(developer accounts have a section below)*

- [Forgotten iCloud email ID and password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182966/forgotten-icloud-email-id-and-password)

#### iTunes Store

- How can I change regions?
- [Can someone help with sorting / merging questions about transferring iTunes store balances?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/)
- [How do you use an existing AppleID on iOS App Store without providing a credit card number?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100955/)
- [How can I use a pre-existing AppleID with Mac App Store without a billing address?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187286/)

#### iOS

- [Forgotten iCloud email ID and password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182966/)
- [Got a new iPhone - where am I supposed to receive the verification code?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291055/)
- [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/how-can-i-bypass-activation-lock)
- What is all this "Other" space on my iPhone/iPad?
- [iTunes sometimes doesn't recognize connected device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116623/)
- [Can I install any iOS version I wish by picking and choosing which firmware to restore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102928/can-i-install-any-ios-version-i-wish-by-picking-and-choosing-which-firmware-to-r)
- [How secure is Activation Lock on iOS 7 (and later)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/) or [Our iPad is locked and we're not sure of the Apple ID / iCloud password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/) or [How can I bypass Activation Lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114985/) These cover locked iOS devices whether you have the iCloud account to unlock it or have to resort to proving ownership to Apple to release the lock.
- [Can I use Siri with these apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297352/can-i-use-siri-with-this-app)
- [How do I jailbreak an iPhone or iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336229/how-do-i-jailbreak-on-x-ios-version/)
- How do I access an older version of an iOS app for my unsupported device?

#### Game Center

- How can I fix my Clash of Clans Villages or online account?

#### Mac / OS X

- How can I boot to recovery and reinstall my OS when my current hard drive isn't recognized or bootable? - [Can't start Mac in recovery mode - only get folder with question mark instead](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337834/)
- [How can I get admin access to a Mac without knowing the current password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password)
- [Is there an easy way to add, modify, or remove what files or URLs are associated with Apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328639/) (this covers file to application mapping and launch services database changes)
- [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x)
- [How can I use Windows to create an OS X El Capitan or macOS Sierra USB flash drive installer from the disk image (.dmg) file downloaded from Apple?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448120/how-to-use-windows-to-create-an-os-x-el-capitan-usb-flash-drive-installer-from-t)
- [macOS Sierra doesn't appear in my Purchased list within the Mac App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286311/macos-sierra-doesnt-appear-in-my-purchased-list-within-the-mac-app-store)
- How can I change PATH in Terminal and make it stick?
- [OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal)
- Memory management and usage (*do I need to say more?*)
- Are Kernel Panics harmful? - [How serious are occasional kernel panics?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74209/)
- [How can I troubleshoot Kernel Panics on my iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/)
- [How serious are occasional kernel panics?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74209/how-serious-are-occasional-kernel-panics)
- My Mac overheats & I see high kernel_task figures - charger-related
  [How to find cause of high kernel_task cpu usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363337/how-to-find-cause-of-high-kernel-task-cpu-usage)
- [Why is kernel_task using so much CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/209575/85275)
- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my drive space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/88313)
- [What does Purgeable mean in Storage under About This Mac section?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252217/what-does-purgeable-means-in-storage-under-about-this-mac-section)
- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac) (with a meta post [discussing this file recovery method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116482/usr-bin-codesign-from-mac-10-9/116483#comment136260_116483))
- [Single application not showing up in Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/236741/88313)
- [Loss of Internet while on VPN on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288995) (VPN split tunnel isn’t allowed)
- [How do I write to NTFS drives in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-do-i-write-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x)
- [What and how does macOS Mojave implement to restrict applications access to personal data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-exactly-does-osx-mojave-implement-to-restrict-access-to-personal-data) (And how to grant applications explicit access)
- [MacBook [Pro] or iMac - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/335322/85275)
- [Which audio interface standard (or API) does macOS use?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336670/which-sound-driver-does-macos-use)
- [Messages on Mac displaying "Not Delivered" but message is being delivered](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316115/messages-on-mac-displaying-not-delivered-but-message-is-being-delivered/)
- [How do I configure Screen Recording permission on macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384228/18101)
- This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90545/18101) about using Apple's 3.5 mm four-pole TRRS jack as a regular line-in port.
- [What are the requirements to use iMac screen as a second monitor - Target Display Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389348/119271)
- My display is broken. Can I set the screen area to just the working part?
  Possibly [Only half of the display works, can I set to display only in that region?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235115/only-half-of-the-display-works-can-i-set-to-display-only-in-that-region) though I feel we need better, still looking.
- [Why do I get a ‘Remote Management’ step when installing macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311052/why-do-i-get-a-remote-management-step-when-installing-macos)
- [How do I add, change or remove a key command from a menu item?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464293/how-do-i-add-change-or-remove-a-key-command-from-a-menu-item)

#### Apple Developer services and accounts.

- [Is it possible to develop an iOS app without a test device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15092/)
- [How to upgrade Individual Developer Account to a Company Account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102961/how-to-upgrade-individual-developer-account-to-a-company-account)
- [What happens when a distribution certificate expires or revoked?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294421/what-happens-when-a-distribution-certificate-expires-or-revoked)
- [What are minimum specs for a MacBook to develop iOS apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3295/) (and possibly [Is the white MacBook suitable for software development?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/) or [Which Mac to develop iPhone apps?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7495))

#### Daemons

- [What is assistantd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57514/what-is-assistantd)
- [What is coreduetd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297391/what-is-coreduetd)
- [What is "hidd"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294666/what-is-hidd)
- [What is nfsd on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178895/what-is-nfsd-on-macos)
- [What is parsecd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266989/what-is-parsecd)
- [What is "secd" process?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159809/what-is-secd)
- [What is touristd?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294291/what-is-touristd)
- [What is "usernoted" and why is it eating my CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212970/what-is-usernoted-and-why-is-it-eating-my-cpu)

Comment: Everyone. Go ahead and ask any question you feel committed to sheparding I to a canonical question. Just post your question and post a link here. Try to tack on to the end of a section and then ping someone in [chat] saying you’d like them to place it where it makes sense to them. That way you’re not promoting yours above others. Cheers and mahalo!

Answer (score 1):

I propose that links to the very good canonical questions (as sourced from the [wiki answer on this question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2419/18101)) should be added to the relevant tag wikis.

For example, [icloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icloud) or [appleid](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appleid) could include a link to this question:

- [Forgotten iCloud email ID and password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182966/forgotten-icloud-email-id-and-password)

I don't expect question askers to necessarily read each tag wiki and find their answers there. Rather, it would make it easier for people to search for duplicate questions and redirect askers to high-quality answers.

Comment: Thanks nic. I’ve made a new section for Apple accounts. I like your idea of linking here for this. Not sure we can link to a section of an answer using anchors perhaps?