# New tag proposal - Canonical or FAQ

Tags: discussion, feature-request, canonical-questions

Re: BMike's question - [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different)

It would seem reasonable that such questions could get their own tag type.

Trying to find them when closing as a dupe is not all that simple. Even when you know the keywords for the dupe search field - for example, I just tested "bypass activation lock" & it turned up 9th in the list. If you're less certain of the title it involves digging through meta to find BMike's QA first.

I even tried "[ios] bypass"... but it's not tagged iOS, it's iPhone.

If we had a [canonical] or [faq] tag type, it would make things a lot simpler, imo.

Opinions?

Comment: Agreed and thanks for this proposal.

Comment: I like the idea, very much so. We may need to actively manage the use of the tag though, to prevent people misuse it.

Comment: (and I've just changed the tag on the bypass question to ios :-)

Comment: @patrix - I was going to mention policing in the question body - but thought that every time someone uses the tag to search, they are reasonably likely to spot any anomalies in the list; so the policing could be quite "accidental" (& thanks :)

Comment: We'll also need a good tag description of course, but something tells me that users don't tend to read them...

Comment: Users read?? What next? Doing research? Being clear & concise? Checking for dupes? What is the world coming to? ;)

Comment: Like the simple yes/no choice answers, btw. Great idea.

Answer (score 4):

## YES

Upvote this answer if you support the idea of creating a `canonical` flag on the main site to identify canonical questions.

Comment: To prevent the misuse of this tag, which I consider more 'important' than regular tags due to the fact we're telling users "here's the above-average, clear answer for your question...", do you think the use should be limited to a higher point level?

Comment: @fsb At first glance I don't see a way to limit the use of a tag to higher-rep users.

Comment: I know that some features are only permitted to users with a specific number of points, I wasn't sure if the use of tags was the same.  I wonder if some of the other SE sites that have canonical flags have problems with people over-using them?  If not, then this is a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

## NO

Upvote this answer if you are against creating a `canonical` flag on the main site.

Answer (score 3):

**Absolutely no.**

This proposal is literally opposing the purpose of tagging: categorising the content of questions. Tags should be about the question content, as defined in the first line of the relevant section of the help center. Meta-tags are also specifically mentioned as later on in the article.

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.

> **Avoid meta-tags**
>   Do not use meta-tags in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>   …

https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Your proposed tag [canonical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical) says nothing about the content of the question. Meta-tagging has been prohibited from Stack Exchange sites for many years now.

> **meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged**

> If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question, it's probably a meta-tag.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: That post is six years old & completely fails to cover any kind of FAQ scenario; the weak subjectivity it berates I totally agree with. We have no mechanism [other than maintaining our own personal reference lists] for quickly searching a canonical post to vote on a dupe.

Comment: @Tetsujin The blog post was to illustrate the background behind the decision — the help center is current and shows the same view. Maintaining a reference list is the same as maintaining a list of questions with a specific tag, except the latter is meta-tagging and shouldn't be used.

Comment: "Shouldn't" is what the community decides, not what legacy dictates. Maintaining a reference list, personal to each user or buried away on a meta-post, is not really the way to be able to recall a canonical database for commonly re-asked questions. Anyway, I've said my piece, I won't vote on this answer either way, I'll see what the community decides on patrick's yes/no vote.

Comment: @Tetsujin I definitely agree with the first statement, but it was the community that decided that meta-tagging was inappropriate. I'm agreeing with them not just because of the legacy but because I agree with the sentiment and the problems caused by the use of meta-tagging. Cheers for this meta discussion by the way!

Comment: Then maybe we don't use "canonical" for a tag but we do something similar to [this practice](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2498) at the Math SE site?  While they refer to these as 'meta tags', they seem like a step-up from a specific tag and a step-down from an overly generic "canonical" tag.  idk, I like the "canonical" tag but definitely see @grgarside's point, too.

Comment: Re: the math meta - these/this tag would never be stand-alone. It would be applied retrospectively. Ideally no-one would 'claim' it on a first answer to a new question, it would be added after some time, as a retroactive action on multi-posts on very similar issues. If it were possible, I'd prefer it to be an admin-only tag, to aid only this one problem, not randomly added to posts by idio... errmmm... users who want to claim a 'rank' [but I doubt that's possible, so some policing/discussion would be required.

Comment: @grgarside - I do agree with your sentiments overall, meta-tagging is not a "good thing". I'm seeing this as a 'quick search' for really 'special' answers that have the community behind them as 'good fit for many situations' QAs

Comment: I agree meta tags are generally bad, but there's always an exception. Consider the FAQ and featured tag in meta. That's a double dose of meta, but having one exception might be worth exploring. I need to think over your good points - imaginary +1 for putting them down in writing.