# Running VirtualBox on Apple M1

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

This question about running VirtualBox or other virtualisation on Apple Silicon has come up several times:

- [Can I run Virtualbox on new M1 Macbook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422565/can-i-run-virtualbox-on-new-m1-macbook-air/422566#422566)
- [How to enable hardware virtualization on MacBook Pro 2020 M1?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408831/how-to-enable-hardware-virtualization-on-macbook-pro-2020-m1)
- [Virtual Box error "Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hadoop" on MacOS Big Sur M1 chip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/416179/virtual-box-error-failed-to-open-a-session-for-the-virtual-machine-hadoop-on-m?rq=1)

The quick answer is no but we have made several attempts to suggest ones that do work. As these are lists and are about the current state they need updating so I suppose are off-topic. However I think we will get asked often enough that we should have an answer so that we maintain it in one place.

I remembered I had answered it and so went to my answer and updated it with details from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/416187/237).
Unfortunately the question I answered is the first given above and has been closed as off-topic (which does seem odd to me)

How do we get a canonical question?

Answer (score 2):

You cam make your own canonical question, then answer it.

It's usually wise to mention that's what you're doing somewhere in the small print & then try to maintain it yourself as best you can after that.

If it seems to get good acceptance from the community, then promote it on [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different)
You always have to be wary of over-promotion… use your best judgement as to whether you seriously think it is worthy of being the canonical.

I've had a couple of goes over the years. One was relatively easy, as the two answers contain references that are likely to remain in place for some time - [MacBook [Pro] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency)
the other took a lot of work to maintain over the years & eventually fell behind anyway, as all the Macs here got stuck on Mojave - [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

So be aware of what you might be letting yourself in for.